# Cant get camera to move through my corridor

Tags: camera

I am having a problem.
Can my problem be caused because there is already an animation in my project?

What I want, a video for a music track of mine.

What I have is a corridor with some kind of red light, reacting to my music.
Next thing I want is the camera to fly through the corridor.

I must be doing something wrong.

At the start I hit I and insert a keyframe location, then go to the end and move camera to end of corridor.
I see two yellow squares appear in the time line.
When I then click in the view port all is gone.
And trying to do calculate I found in a question like this does not work either.

Is there maybe a good tutorial explaining this?

A vid of what I have now, so you guys can get an idea on what I am after.
The corridor I have is now much longer then in the vid.
Start frame is 1, end frame is 6600.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbJrFz2nKls

---

Although I now have a new problem, I was using the wrong constrain.

Maybe I can redo the keyframes, because now my camera starts at the end.

Think I am gonna take a short break. Lost count on how many tutorials I watched, and it never works like that in my project.

Maybe I will start with new simple file, to see if I can figure this camera movement, and then find the issue in my project.

I do wonder if my problems come from another animation.
All tutorial I see have only one animation.

Mine has two, red lights reacting to my music track, and then the camera moving animation.

Maybe I should add the music track last?

Edit: I am getting desperate, somebody on Blender artist said I was doing it wrong I needed to add a plane add a curve modefier, and parent the camera to the plane.
Although the plane does what I want, the camera like before refuses to work along.
No matter what I try, like the other solutions given to me, the camera refuses to work along.
I hope somebody can help me, I hope I packed the file right with the mp3, that is used to animate the red lights. There is a license on the music track, but that comes down to, as long as you admit you got it from me, you can with it what you like.(its also on soundcloud)

[image]

A picture showing the issue, were the plane is, the camera should be too:
[image]

Edit:
Somebody had a look at my file, and his conclusion is **that there is an issue with my file**. I will be starting over with a new file, then make the path, plane and camera working, and then add back the other stuff, to see if I can find were the problem comes from.

Comment: I do not understand why you accepted an answer and keep on asking more questions on the same post. If the issue was resolved then ask further questions in a different post. If the answer didn't solve the issue then don't mark it as accepted.

Comment: I might be better off starting a new question, but I can explain what I did.
I have a problem, then somebody told me how to do it. I tried that but it did not work in my file.

It does how ever work, when I start a new file, that's why I marked it as accepted.

I just removed the accepted tag though.
  
I added the blend file posted a new picture, but nobody seems to see this? 
It was what you and others who told me to do this, edit the original post.

Not looking for an argument, but getting confused on what you want me to ?
I even put the word edit in front of my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to press I twice, the first time to set the keyframe at the start of the animation and the second time to define the end of the animation

Comment: I am still not getting it fully but I have my camera moving although very slow.
Progress :) 
Pressing I twice seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Almost there:

https://youtu.be/MMXg4ssXzWc

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Follow Path Constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/follow_path.html) on your camera. Here is an simple example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dMD8ihmkiA

Make sure to click "Follow Curve" on the Camera's Follow Path Constraint:
[image]

Comment: That looks like what I need but I can't get it to work.
As we type I have the camera follow the path ( clamp to path constrain)
But the camera keeps looking straight ahead, instead of looking a the directing of the bezier curve.

When I try to use the follow path constrain working. it seems I am not allowed to select my bezier curve. it askes for a camera ? but what ever I select, nothing happens.

This is what I have now:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMXg4ssXzWc

Comment: Make sure you click "Follow Curve" on the camera constraint

Answer (score 1):

There is another really cool method I learned from this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7qyW1G350g

Basically, you use auto key frames while moving the camera manually in walk mode using the WASD keys (like a video game), then use keyframe resampling to smooth the motion out.

Answer (score 0):

I was again having issues inserting a keyframe, and found this:

[Can't insert keyframe in blender 2.81](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162124/cant-insert-keyframe-in-blender-2-81)

> You have to press [I] while holding your mouse on whatever you want to
> make a key frame on.

Comment: I finally got it working. https://blenderartists.org/t/animate-camera-problem/1241041

Things I did wrong:
Origins of the path, plane and camera not lined up.
The way I parented the camera to the plane. I used the option from the right site of the screen, but should have done, object, parent, vertex triangle.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz5DDCSuZP4&feature=youtu.be

To do:
Fix some caps and add a bit more details to some places, and figure out how to speed up the camera.